# NodeJS, How to get new token with refresh token using google api?

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-nodejs-client

Following google api doc https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/nodejs, could not find a way to get a new token using refresh token with the oauth2 client.

The doc says: 
`"The application should store the refresh token for future use and use the access token to access a Google API. Once the access token expires, the application uses the refresh token to obtain a new one."`

How to you get the new token using the refresh token with google oAuth2 Client ?

So far I have managed using a simple post

```
const getTokenWithRefresh = async (refresh_token) => {
  return axios
  .post("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", {
    client_id: clientId,
    client_secret: clientSecret,
    refresh_token: refresh_token,
    grant_type: "refresh_token",
  })
  .then((response) => {
    // TODO save new token here
    console.log("response", response.data.access_token);
    return response.data;
  })
  .catch((response) => console.log("error", response))
}
```

But ideally would like to see cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Refresh tokens dont expire as long as they are used why would you want to get a new one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
const {google} = require('googleapis')


const getTokenWithRefresh = (secret, refreshToken) => {

    let oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
           secret.clientID,
           secret.clientSecret,
           secret.redirectUrls
    )

    oauth2Client.credentials.refresh_token = refreshToken

    oauth2Client.refreshAccessToken( (error, tokens) => {
           if( !error ){
                // persist tokens.access_token
                // persist tokens.refresh_token (for future refreshs)
           }
    })

}
```

`refreshAccessToken()` is deprecated (and I really wonder why). But as it still works, this is still my way to go

Comment: Though `refreshAccessToken()` is deprecated, you could use `getRequestHeaders()` which does the same!

Comment: It is giving me the same refresh token which i pased that is:
tokens.refresh_token. why is that? It should give the new refresh token right?

Answer (score 4):

Your code is I think correct maybe you missed something but I've tried the following code in my NodeJS application, and its working well.

```
let tokenDetails = await fetch("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", {
    "method": "POST",
    "body": JSON.stringify({
        "client_id": {your-clientId},
        "client_secret": {your-secret},
        "refresh_token": {your-refreshToken},
        "grant_type": "refresh_token",
    })
});
tokenDetails = await tokenDetails.json();
console.log("tokenDetails");
console.log(JSON.stringify(tokenDetails,null,2));  // => Complete Response
const accessToken = tokenDetails.access_token;  // => Store access token
```

Above code will return following response if your all data are correct then:

```
{
  "access_token": "<access-token>",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/business.manage",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

Comment: I am getting `id_token` in response with these property you mentioned above, what is `id_token` in this response?

Comment: Hello @KamalHossain, Are you using the same API?

Comment: This solution is no longer required for me, I have used this finally [react google login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login). @Keyur Chavda-kc1994

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getAccessToken = async () => {
    try {
        let tokenDetails = await axios.post("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token", {
            "client_id": {your-clientId},
            "client_secret": {your-secret},
            "refresh_token": {your-refreshToken}
            grant_type: "refresh_token",
        })

        const accessToken = tokenDetails.data.access_token
        return accessToken
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }

}

getAccessToken()
.then(data=> console.log(data))
.catch(err => console.log(err))
```

I think This might help you !
Happy Coding !